# Why am I getting error when I try to pass optional boolean argument in compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, optional-parameters, jetpack-compose-navigation

I defined my screen in Jetpack Compose like this,

**my screen sealed class:**

```
sealed class RegisterScreen(val route: String) {
    object SignUpVerificationPhoneCodeScreen : 
        RegisterScreen("verification_phone_code_screen")
}
```

---

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navHostController: NavHostController
    var startDestination:String=""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val isTokenExist: Boolean = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_TOKEN_EXIST, false)
        val refreshTokenResponse: NavigateState? = intent.getParcelableExtra(NAVIGATE_STATE_RESPONSE)

        refreshTokenResponse?.let {
            startDestination = navigateIfNeeded(it,isTokenExist)
        }


        setContent {

            Theme {
                navHostController = rememberNavController()
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    RootNavGraph(navHostController = navHostController, startDestination)
                }
            }
        }
    }


private fun navigateIfNeeded(response: NavigateState, isTokenExist:Boolean): String {

    return when {
        !isTokenExist -> RegisterScreen.SignUpStartRegisterScreen.route
        response.hasValidation == 0 ->  "${RegisterScreen.SignUpVerificationPhoneCodeScreen.route}?$IS_REDIRECT_FROM_LOGIN_OR_SPLASH=true"
        response.hasValidation == 1 -> {
            when (response.eatingHabit) {
                0 -> {
                    if (response.weight == 0 || response.goalWeight == 0) {
                        return RegisterScreen.SignUpDailyCalorieGoalScreen.route
                    } else{
                        return DASHBOARD_ROUTE
                    }
                }
                else -> RegisterScreen.SignUpPaymentScreen.route
            }
        }
        else -> DASHBOARD_ROUTE
    }
}
```

}

**RootNavGraph**

```
@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String
) {

    val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = viewModel()

    val startRoute = if (startDestination != DASHBOARD_ROUTE) REGISTER_LOGIN_ROUTE else DASHBOARD_ROUTE

    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = startRoute,
        route = ROOT_ROUTE
    )
    {
        registerLoginNavGraph(navHostController, sharedViewModel,startDestination)
        dashBoardNavGraph(navHostController, sharedViewModel)
        
    }
}
```

**RegisterLoginNavGraph**

```
 fun NavGraphBuilder.registerLoginNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    startDestination:String
) {

   val _startDestination =  if(startDestination == "") RegisterScreen.SignUpStartRegisterScreen.route else startDestination

    navigation(
        startDestination = _startDestination,
        route = REGISTER_LOGIN_ROUTE
    ) {

        composable(
            route = "${RegisterScreen.SignUpVerificationPhoneCodeScreen.route}?$EMAIL={$EMAIL}&$PHONE={$PHONE}&$IS_REDIRECT_FROM_LOGIN_OR_SPLASH={$IS_REDIRECT_FROM_LOGIN_OR_SPLASH}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(EMAIL) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = ""
                },
                navArgument(PHONE) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = ""
                },
                navArgument(IS_REDIRECT_FROM_LOGIN_OR_SPLASH) {
                    type = NavType.BoolType
                    defaultValue = false
                }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->

            VerificationPhoneCodeRoute(
                navHostController,
                sharedViewModel,
                userPhone = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(PHONE),
                userEmail = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(EMAIL),
                isRedirectFromLoginOrSplash = backStackEntry.arguments?.getBoolean(
                    IS_REDIRECT_FROM_LOGIN_OR_SPLASH)
            )
        }

   

    }
}
```

When I use like that in **navigateIfNeeded** function in MainActivity

```
 "${RegisterScreen.SignUpVerificationPhoneCodeScreen.route}?$IS_REDIRECT_FROM_LOGIN_OR_SPLASH=true"
```

However I get this error,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination verification_phone_code_screen?isRedirectFromLoginOrSplash=true is not a direct child of this NavGraph

I don't have to send other optional parameters like email and phone, right? because they are already optional? Isn't it supposed to work this way? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can see from the recent edit that this is a nested navigation use-case. From which Composable are you navigating? Is it in same graph?

Comment: You should use the route of the nested navigation if you are navigating from a different graph.

Comment: registerLoginNavGraph is inside the RootNavGraph. you can see the above. How can I do that you said . can you give an example ?